# Constructing Invariant Lamination of a Pseudo-Anosov Given By Dehn Twists

Tags: reference-request, gt.geometric-topology, mapping-class-groups, foliations

The simplest case of a well known theorem of Penner states that given a pair of filling curves, a positive twist about one curve together with a negative twist about the other curve is a pseudo-anosov mapping class. Suppose I have an explicit pair of curves that fill a closed surface, is there a reasonable way to explicitly compute the stable and unstable laminations of this map?

Comment: I believe Mark Bell at UIUC has thought about this, see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.00829.pdf).

Comment: Penner's proof gives a very explicit description, in terms of a specific train track and specific Perron-Frobenius matrix on the branches of that train track, the eigenvector of which gives weights on those branches that determine the stable lamination. Similarly for the unstable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is explicitly answered in Section 6 of Thurston's Bulletin article, freely available [here](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183554722).  In the end it boils down to a calculation in $\mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{Z})$.